# Can we eliminate negative value in crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I wrote a program in C#. But in my data there are some negative values. There is problem showing negative value on graph. Also my graph is not updating according to value. Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. Fix your data
2. Modify the query, or use a Crystal function to use ABS()
3. Modify the query so that negative values are not included in the result set.
4. Post this in an appropriate location.